# MVC Error on (Almost Default) Individual User Account Creation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, user-accounts

I'm relatively new to MVC, and I kicked off with the default MVC project template in visual studio 2013 (Express).
I modified the views to suit my needs (temporarily), then followed [this tutorial](http://www.aubrett.com/InformationTechnology/WebDevelopment/MVC/CustomMVC5UserFields.aspx) to add 3 new fields to the user registration process. I added BirthDate and Email as in the tutorial, and a third one: FirstName. Everything built and published fine.

After this, I uploaded the published site to my domain [here](http://www.spiderhouse.org) and tested in Chrome. All of the pages load correctly, but when I try to register a user, I get taken to the "Error" page. I've checked the JS console and the only entry is: `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.`

Here is the code for my C# classes as shown in the tutorial above:

Account/Register View (New fields):

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
```

Account ViewModel (Register ViewModel New Fields):

```
[Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Identity Model (ApplicationUser Method):

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Account Controller (Post:Register Method):

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName, BirthDate = model.BirthDate, Email = model.Email, FirstName = model.FirstName };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Please could you let me know if you think you know what is causing the error page (I'll leave it live so you can see for yourself) or if you know how I can find out the specific error. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Update 1:** I get taken to the same error pag on logging in rather than being told a username is not in database. Is this meant to happen?

**Update 2:** It runs fine locally.

Comment: Could possibly because of datacontext changes since creation.
Try deleting the database, so the EF could create new DB with the updated schema.

Comment: @MillerKoijam I notice that no appdata folder is present either in the publish directory or on the site (viewed via ftp). Could this be related? :)

Comment: what error is thrown when you run it locally?

Comment: No error is thrown locally - the account is created successfully.

Comment: Should I rebuild and publish again?

Comment: @MillerKoijam seeing as it runs ok locally what could change in the published server version?

Comment: What's the text of the error?  Check the Event Log on the server.

Comment: How do I check the event log? The console just says: `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.`

Comment: @JoshKodroff You can check for yourself if you want at http://www.spiderhouse.org/Account/Register as there's no chance of you registering as it doesn't work ;)

Comment: @samdy1 In order for anyone to effectively help you, you're going to need to get the text of the exception.

Comment: How can I find this if it runs ok locally? @JoshKodroff

Comment: You need to log on to the server and look at the Event Log (Event Viewer).  Alternatively, you can log on to the server and try in a local browser and you should see the error details (the Yellow Screen of Death).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51030/discussion-between-samdy1-and-josh-kodroff)